# MySql Query does not return any value even though it Exists in the table (C# Asp.net)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I encountered a problem while trying to verify if a value exists in the database. I use Visual Studio 2017. 
I wrote a function that checks if Username is in the database table:

```
protected bool userIsAdmin(string user)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    string loginQuery = "select count(*) from AdminTable where User= @Username";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(loginQuery, con);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user);
    user = user.Trim();

    int rows;
    rows = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (rows != 0)
    {
        OutputLabel.Text = "You are logged";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        OutputLabel.Text = "Try again";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I eliminated the probability of an outside error by calling this function like this:
`if(userIsAdmin("uia94881"){...}`

My database table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psPDI.png)

Comment: Well, if you use MySql then you should use its classes, not the ones that works only with Sql Server. You should not be able to even open the connection

Comment: `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` is unnecessary. It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: It looks like you are re-using the `connection` and `cmd` from a globally declared variable. Don't do that. Other that that the code itself works....

Comment: Perhaps it's connecting to a different database?

Comment: Run the query in your SQL Server, and see what it returns.

Comment: It is connecting to my database. I forgot to mention, my database has two tables. With one table I have no problem getting data, but with this one it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script as below,

```
string loginQuery = "select count(*) from AdminTable where [User]= @Username";
```

because User is a built in function in SQL Server, which will give you the Database  username.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This thing gave me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("PUT YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE");

string loginQuery = "SELECT (User) FROM AdminTable WHERE User = @Username";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(loginQuery, connection);

adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user);
DataSet usr = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(usr)

foreach(DataRow dr in usr.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 
  string user += usr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User"].ToString();
}
if(user != "")
{
    OutputLabel.Text = "Try again";
    return false;
}
else
{
    OutputLabel.Text = "You are logged";
    return true;
}
```

Try this instead!

Comment: I get the following error on line  `adapt.Fill(usr); `  :  System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal to a known managed provider native type.'

Comment: @LeonidTanas I edited it a bit, copy all that. Replace "PUT YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE" with ur own constring. And tell me if u get an error. :)

Comment: It still returns false(  I think there might be a problem with my table or something. My database has two tables, and with the first one there is no problem and I am able to  perform any of these actions, but with the second it doesn't work. Maybe it's just a Visual Studio thing.